# Loop interation inside @each directive

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm trying to iterate over a loop of items which is being included via the `@each` directive in Laravel Blade.

When I use a regular `@foreach` loop, this works perfectly fine and I can iterate over odd/even records, but when using `@each`, this concept doesn't seem to be working.

Am I doing something wrong or is this expected behaviour of the `@each` directive?

My code is as follows:

**splits.blade.php**

```html
<section>
    @each('_partials/components.split', $page->splits, 'split')
</section>
```

**split.blade.php**

```html
<article
    @if ($loop->odd)
        style="background-image: url('placehold.it/1920x400');"
        class="bg-cover bg-center"
    @else
        class="bg-white"
    @endif
    >
</article>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks

Matt

Comment: FYI, you should be doing your styling in CSS using [the `nth-child` selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)

Comment: @miken32 Hey. Thanks for your comment. I actually use utility classes like the TailwindCSS framework, 9/10 it solves the need to write actual CSS, speeding up my build time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each doesn't include $loop variable in blade file automatically but passes `$key` variable.

So you can write:

```
<article
    @if ($key % 2 == 0)
        style="background-image: url('placehold.it/1920x400');"
        class="bg-cover bg-center"
    @else
        class="bg-white"
    @endif
    >
</article>
```

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly and get's round the whole odd/even conditions using the modulus operator.

Answer (score 1):

The each directive does not have the `$loop` variable like foreach.

However, it does send the key of every item in the provided array to the view. So if you did not set custom keys, the `$key` variable should contain a value from `0` to the length of your array.

Just found this out by looking in [the source code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/0b12ef19623c40e22eff91a4b48cb13b3b415b25/src/Illuminate/View/Factory.php#L194).

Comment: Brilliant, thank you! Works perfectly doing it via a modulus operator.